# Python / remove duplicate from each group if condition meets in the group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete the rows in each group if there is the duplicate only in particular value of a column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'channel':['X','Y','Y','X','X','A','X'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
})
```

[image]

I want to keep the rows in each group only with first occurence of X and delete others as below

[image]

I tried below code but this delets all rows that have duplicate channel value irrespective of whther channel = X or not

```
df = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(subset='channel', keep='first') if 'X' in x['channel'].values else x)
```

Comment: Please post sample fo original data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets create a boolean mask for filtering the required rows

```
mask = df['channel'].eq('X') & df.duplicated(subset=['group', 'channel'])
```

Result

```
df[~mask]

  group channel  value
0     A       X      1
1     A       Y      2
2     B       Y      3
3     B       X      3
5     C       A      5
6     C       X      5
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham but would it not delete all duplicated rows because mask will have all duplicated rows and I want to keep the first occurence

Comment: This is working on this sample data but not working on actual data, in actual data all duplicates are getting deleted.